# How to execute program via ssh on a remote machine display

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm using Linux as a client and windows as a server and I want to display executing program on my windows machine (something like -display :0 option in X systems) wihout installing additional software (X server). I've tried to use runas (runas /user:username "notepad.exe") but it seems it doesn't work the way it should (There's proccess of notepad but still no window open ) What can I do ?